# How to validate form using several functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, field

The two function work perfectly but im only able to use one at a time, the form should check password and link the user to other pages based on the selected radio button. Is there a way to make it work??

Function to verify password.

```
function check() 
{ 
   var password=document.getElementById('password');
   var confirm=document.getElementById('confirm'); 

   if(password==confirm) 
   { 
       return true; 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      alert('Password do not match'); 
      return false; 
   } 

}
```

function 2: direct user to 2 different html pages based on selection

```
function doSubmit(form) 
{ 
   var urls = form['url']; 
   var i = urls && urls.length; 
   while (i--) 
   { 
     if (urls[i].checked) 
     { 
       window.location = urls[i].value; 
     } 
   } 
     return false; 
}
```

Here is the html code( I have included only the part which are related to these functions)

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return check()">


   <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" maxlength="20" size="10" required="true"    pattern=".{7,}" title="Password should be atleast 7 characters long"/>

   <br /><br />

  <label for="confirm">Confirm Password</label>
   <input type="password" id="confirm"" maxlength="20" size="10" required="true"   />
    <label for="mcq">MCQ</label>
   Beginner<input type="radio" name="url" value="begin" id="rdbegin"  value="beginner.html"required="true"/>
   <br />
  Expert<input type="radio" name="url" value="expert" id="rdexpert" value="expert.html"required="true"/>
  <br /><br />

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: did you try to call `doSubmit()` from inside `check()`?

Comment: yes i also tried that, i called the function just after the if else statement, i even inserted them in a wrapper function but it didn't work, basically check() works fine, im able to validate the passwords but doSubmit() doen't wor, the page just refreshes after i click on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Try this to get the radio button value:

```
function doSubmit(form) 
{ 
     var urls = form['url']; 
     console.log(urls.value);
     window.location = urls.value;
}
```

Also use `.value` to get the passwords values:

```
var password=document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Otherwise the following condition will be always false:

```
if(password==confirm) // because you were comparing two html nodes
```

Here's the **[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bx68uepw/)**.

---

You can simply call your second function inside your first one after validation, like this:

```
function check() 
{ 
   var password=document.getElementById('password');
   var confirm=document.getElementById('confirm'); 

   if(password==confirm) 
   { 
       var form = document.getElementById('form'); //give id="form" to your form
       doSubmit(form);
       return true; 
   } 
   else 
   { 
      alert('Password do not match'); 
      return false; 
   } 

}
```

And for the `onSubmit()` function avoid the use of the `while`loop which will cause an infinite loop because `i--` will always be true, you can simply do:

```
var urls = form['url']; 
for(var i=0; urls[i]; ++i){
   if(urls[i].checked){
         console.log(urls[i].value); //try printing the url and see what it gets
         window.location = urls[i].value; // also change this to urls[i]
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but im getting the same problem, the form just refreshes upon submit, im only having this problem when i include doSubmit() in the form, if i use it seperately it directs me to the pages i specify. I also tried calling doSubmit within the form tag just to see if it works, but im getting an error "page couldn't be found"

Comment: could you post the html code, so we can see the urls?

Comment: <form action="" onsubmit="return check()"><label for="mcq">MCQ</label>
   Beginner<input type="radio" name="rdomcq" value="begin" id="rdbegin" value="beginner.html"required="true"/>
   <br />
  Expert<input type="radio" name="rdomcq" value="expert" id="rdexpert" value="expert.html"required="true"/>
  <br /><br />

  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: No, I meant the whole html code, try to print the url to the console, see my EDIT.

Comment: okay, please give me a moment im trying to paste the code here,

Comment: could you please give me a step by step explanation on how to post you my html code, I'm not able to do it properly

Comment: Use the `edit` button under your post(question) and paste the code there, then confirm your edit.

Comment: I have posted the code, i only included the necessary parts,

Comment: Okay I think the problem is caused by this `value="expert"` and `value="begin"` try to remove them from your radio buttons because in that case you will be redirected to `expert` and not to `expert.html`.

And if they are radio buttons you can select the value using `form['url'].value;`

Comment: Still the same issue, I think i will direct the user to another page where he will be able to make the selections.

Comment: What does `console.log(urls[i].value);` give you in the console(F12 in your browser)??

Comment: There is nothing in the console.

Comment: And what if you change it to `console.log(form['url'].value);` outside the for loop.

Comment: No still the same issue, the inputs are not logged, but if i use the same function in another html page then it works fine.

Comment: something appears but it refreshes very quickly.

Comment: It's working as expected take a look at the **DEMO** in my **EDIT**.